# set transaction limit for each token

Tags: solidity, ether, tokens

Is it possible to set a limit for the number of transaction each token can have in solidity? for example, a token can only transfer 10 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can do it with simple variable:

```
uint8 public txMax = 10;
uint8 public txPerformed;
```

then in method:

```
function someFunc() {
    require(txPerformed < txMax, "no more transactions");
    //   ur code here
    txPerformed = txPerformed.add(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ERC20 tokens are fungible. Any one unit (or sub unit) of an ERC20 token is identical to others.

Due to this, it isn't possible to limit transfers on a token-bases. You could limit the ability of addresses to transfer the token, but limiting the token itself is not possible, since you cannot tell which unit of a token has been transferred before.

ERC721 tokens would support this, however, since they are non-fungible. You could include an attribute in the ERC721 token that counts the number of times it has been transferred.